# How to binarize an image when image has white text on black background and vice versa?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to binarize an image for OCR. I have attached the code which take image data as input and return binary image and this method works for most of the image.

For e.g,

- Original:

[image: Original Image Sample]

- Result:

[image: Binarized Image of Sample]

```
def preprocessing(image):
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blured1 = cv2.medianBlur(image, 3)
    blured2 = cv2.medianBlur(image, 51)
    divided = np.ma.divide(blured1, blured2).data
    normed = np.uint8(255 * divided / divided.max())
    th, image = cv2.threshold(normed, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    image = cv2.erode(image, np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8))
    image = cv2.dilate(image, np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8))
    return image
```

But when I applied the same method on below attached images it won't work as per the expectation. It should give image which has readable text for tesseract input.

- Original Image 1:

[image: Original Image 1]

- Pre processed image:

[image: Pre processed image]

- Original Image 2:

[image: Original Image 2]

- Pre processed image:

[image: Pre processed image]

Comment: You need to visualize the intermediate output images for every step in `preprocessing`. Analyze each result and come up with a general approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably try to disassemble the image yourself. I think the Bradley-Roth algorithm ([Bradley-Roth Adaptive Thresholding Algorithm - How do I get better performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091755/)) could help you with a slight modification - if the neighborhood is brighter than 128, then what is darker is highlighted, if the neighborhood is darker than 128, then what is lighter is highlighted.

Comment: thanks its works for my use case, I have to tweak threshold value according my input and it work pretty much good than previous logic.